# Integral identity involving sin(x)/x

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Prove or disprove

$$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{3 \sin \left( x\right )}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{4 \sin ^ 3\left( x\right )}{x^3} \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: It is not terribly suprising that two definite integrals are related to each other by a constant scale factor.  I would expect nothing less.

Comment: @Tpofofn why dont you solve the problem then, if nothing is surprising

Comment: What is there to prove?   A more proper question would be to ask how to integrate the right hand side if that is what you are trying to figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any integral of the form
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n\,dx $$
can be computed through integration by parts: it is enough to compute the Fourier sine series of $\sin^n x$, differentiate it $(n-1)$ times and exploit:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(mx)}{x}\,dx = \pi.$$
In this case, the result directly follows from the identity:
$$ \sin(3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x,$$
leading to:
$$ 4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^3\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{x^3}\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{9\sin(3x)-3\sin x}{x}\,dx=3\pi.$$

Comment: I like you tending to find generalizations. Thanks.